# One-bit comparator syntax errors

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to write a code for a one bit comparator, but I keep getting errors. Any help?

```
//onebit_comparator code

module onebit_comparator(
input wire a,b; 
output wire equation);

wire X0,X1;

assign X0 = -a & b;

assign X1 = a & b;

assign equation = X0|X1;

endmoule;
```

Errors

```
10170 Verilog HDL syntax error at onebit_comparator.v(4) neat text: "output"; expecting ")".

10112 Ignored design unit "onebit_comparator" at onebit_comaparator.v(2) due to previous errors

10170 Verilog HDL syntax error at onebit_comparator.v(12) near text: ";"; expecting a description
```

Comment: Did you also mean `X0 = ~a & ~b;` ? The logic as it is currently written is equivalent to `equation = b;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 syntax errors and one typo.

Change:

```
input wire a,b;
```

to:

```
input wire a,b,
```

You must use a comma instead of a semicolon to separate the ports.

`endmoule` is a typo; you meant to type `endmodule`

You must not use a semicolon after the `endmodule` keyword (or any other `end`-type keyword, such as `endcase`, etc.).

Here is the complete code without syntax errors:

```
module onebit_comparator( 
input wire a,b,
output wire equation);

wire X0,X1;

assign X0 = -a & b;

assign X1 = a & b;

assign equation = X0|X1;

endmodule
```